# Selecting an Item from a Spinner in Android and then displaying an object

Tags: android, button, android-spinner

after tweaking my ASyncTask classes to grab the information that I need, I now have another issue.

Essentially, here is my scenario:

After adjusting the ASyncTask for the ManifestItems, I also created an ASyncTask class for Consignments, as a Consignment is a ManifestItem. Essentially, what the app should do is display the details of a Consignment (in a new Activity) when a ManifestItem in the Spinner is selected.

I tried implementing the OnSelectedItemListener class but that didn't hit the breakpoint. Based on my code below, what approach can I take? Thanks.

```
package com.signonglass;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.json.*;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private final static String POD_URI = "http://192.168.0.105:8092/PodCore.svc";
private EditText evManifestCode;
private Spinner list_job;
private String jobName;
private Button btnSearch;
ArrayList<ManifestItemObj> jobList = new ArrayList<ManifestItemObj>();
ArrayList<ConsignmentItems> conItemList = new ArrayList<ConsignmentItems>();
Consignments con = new Consignments();
String consignment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    evManifestCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.manifest);
    list_job = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.jobSpinner);
    btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

}

//ASyncTask to get ManifestItem from each manifest
public class getManifestItems extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ManifestItemObj>>
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String theString = "";
    StringBuilder builder;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading manifests...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener()
        {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0)
            {
                getManifestItems.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ManifestItemObj> doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        try
        {
            //http get request
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(POD_URI + "/getJobs/" + evManifestCode.getText().toString());
            //set the hedear to get the data in JSON format
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            //get the response
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            //read content
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            builder.append(line);
                    }
            is.close(); 
            theString = builder.toString();

            JSONObject jobsJSON = new JSONObject(theString);
            JSONArray jobs = jobsJSON.getJSONArray("getJobsResult");

            for(int i = 1; i < jobs.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject mit = jobs.getJSONObject(i);
                ManifestItemObj mi = new ManifestItemObj();
                mi.ManifestItemID = mit.getInt("ManifestItemID");
                mi.JobType = mit.getString("JobType");
                mi.FKID = mit.getInt("FKID");
                jobList.add(mi);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jobList;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ManifestItemObj> mio)
    {
        ManifestItemAdapter mia = new ManifestItemAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, jobList);
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        list_job.setAdapter(mia);

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ManifestItemObj selectedJob = jobList.get(position);
        jobName = selectedJob.getJobType() + Integer.toString(selectedJob.getConsignmentID());
        consignment = jobName;

        if(position != 0)
        {
            showToast(jobName + " " + "was selected!");
            new getConsignment().execute(jobName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }*/
}

public class getConsignment extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Consignments>
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String theString = "";
    StringBuilder builder;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading consignments...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener()
        {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0)
            {
                getConsignment.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Consignments doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
        try
        {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String theString = new String("");
            //http get request
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(POD_URI + "/getJobDetails/" + consignment);
            //set the hedear to get the data in JSON format
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            //get the response
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            is.close();

            theString = builder.toString();

            JSONObject conJSON = new JSONObject(theString);
            JSONArray cons = conJSON.getJSONArray("getJobDetailsResult");

            for(int i = 0; i < cons.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject cObj = cons.getJSONObject(i);
                con.ConsignmentID = cObj.getInt("ConsignmentID");
                con.ConsignmentCreationDate = cObj.getString("ConsignmentCreationDate");
                con.ConsignmentCustRef = cObj.getString("ConsignmentCustRef");
                con.OrderNo = cObj.getString("OrderNo");
                con.ConsignmentActive = cObj.getBoolean("ConsignmentActive");
                con.JobType = cObj.getString("JobType");

                //Client object
                JSONObject clObj = cObj.getJSONObject("Client");
                Clients cl = new Clients();
                cl.ClientId = clObj.getInt("ClientID");
                cl.ClientName = clObj.getString("ClientName");
                con.Clients = cl;

                //ShipTo object
                JSONObject stObj = cObj.getJSONObject("ShipTo");
                ShipTo sto = new ShipTo();
                sto.ShipToId = stObj.getInt("ShipToId");
                sto.ShipToName = stObj.getString("ShipToName");
                sto.ShipToAddress1 = stObj.getString("ShipToAddress1");
                sto.ShipToAddress2 = stObj.getString("ShipToAddress2");
                sto.ShipToCity = stObj.getString("ShipToCity");
                sto.ShipToPostcode = stObj.getString("ShipToPCode");
                sto.ShipToState = stObj.getString("ShipToState");
                con.ShipTo = sto;

                //FreightZone object
                JSONObject fzObj = cObj.getJSONObject("FreightZone");
                FreightZones fz = new FreightZones();
                fz.FreightZoneID = fzObj.getInt("FreightZoneId");
                fz.FreightZone = fzObj.getString("FreightZone");
                con.FreightZone = fz;

                JSONArray conItems = cObj.getJSONArray("ConsignmentItems");

                for(int m = 0; m < conItems.length(); m++)
                {
                    JSONObject cit = conItems.getJSONObject(m);
                    ConsignmentItems ci = new ConsignmentItems();
                    ci.ConsignmentItemID = cit.getInt("ConsignmentItemsID");
                    ci.Quantity = cit.getInt("QTY");

                    //get Product from ConsignmentItems
                    JSONObject pro = cit.getJSONObject("Products");
                    Products prod = new Products();
                    prod.ProductId = pro.getInt("ProductID");
                    prod.ProductModel = pro.getString("ProductModel");
                    prod.ItemsPerCarton = pro.getInt("PerCarton");
                    prod.ProductDescription = pro.getString("Description");
                    prod.Height = (float) pro.getDouble("Height");
                    prod.Length = (float) pro.getDouble("Length");
                    prod.Width = (float) pro.getDouble("Width");
                    prod.Cubic = (float) pro.getDouble("Cubic");
                    ci.Product = prod;
                    conItemList.add(ci);
                    con.ConsignmentItems = conItemList;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Consignments conselect)
    {
        ShowItemsOfManifest(con);
    }

}

public void ShowItemsOfManifest(Consignments consignments)
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ConActivity.class);
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    newIntent.putExtra("Consignment", consignments);

    this.startActivity(newIntent);

}

public void btnSearchClick(View view)
{
    new getManifestItems().execute();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the listener to your `Spinner`. Something like

```
list_job = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.jobSpinner);
btnSearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

list_job.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  // add the listener here
```

and implement the listener

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
```

Comment: Hi @codeMagic, is it possible for me to do this? 

`public class getManifestItems extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ManifestItemObj>> implements OnItemSelectedListener?`

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. You could try it and see what happens. But, if your `Spinner` is a public variable of the class and the `AsyncTask` is an inner class of your `Activity` then you wouldn't need to because `onPostExecute()` would still have access to the `Spinner`. But I don't see why you couldn't do it, although I've never tried

Comment: Ultimately, what I've had to do now is "upgrade" the program to add yet another AsyncTask (pointing to another service and another database) to get a Manifest object from the IMEI number. 

I have asked the question here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350477/using-imei-as-a-parameter-for-json-service

The reason I'm asking was because there was a clash between the Spinner and Button controls, where I was seen "casting" it.